# How to retrieve all meta data directly from the $post object? Such as $post->related_topics?

Tags: posts, post-meta

I set up a meta field `related_topics` that I use to associate `lesson` `topics` to a custom post type `lesson`.

I read here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640850/wordpress-how-to-return-meta-with-query-posts

that you can access meta fields directly from a post object in the manner `$post->my_field`.

For a given `lesson` there could be several related `topics`. For a given `lesson` that has multiple `topics`, I noticed that `$post->related_topics` only returns the first `topic` instance, when in fact there are more than one. Is there some method to use, something like `$post->related_topics->all()`? Maybe with this convention only one item is returned by default even if there is a collection?

thanks,
Brian

Comment: `$post->related_topics` is not a standard field on the `WP_Post` object (the post object only contains the data from the `wp_posts` table). Are you adding this?

Comment: When you have custom fields as meta data where the field has an id of the post you can get the data in the way I mention. Just learned about it yesterday. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640850/wordpress-how-to-return-meta-with-query-posts In my case, I have a  related_topics meta field and for the post in question there are 4 related topics. But $post->related_topics is only returning one item.

Comment: The post object is only going to return what you put into it. You're using `get_post_meta()` to get the data you're putting into it, so that's really what you should be asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling $post->related_topics you are using the magic functions of the object ( __get and __isset )

To make it simple, behind the scenes it is the same as :

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'related_topics', true );
```

So you are just abstracting the use of the function [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). And as you can see, the third argument is defined as TRUE. And this tells the function to return a single value.

So its ok if your meta is a single value, but if you have multiple values, then you must set the third argument as false. Thus you shouldn't use the magic functions, but rather call get_post_meta yourself.

So, just use :

```
$topics = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'related_topics', false);
```

like that you have an array of values

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to just access all my data using $post->some_other_data sort of syntax but I guess I will just use the meta function. thanks, Brian